# DOM4J validate xml against DTD provided at runtime

Tags: dtd, xml-validation, dom4j

I need to validate a multiple files produced by a third party against a DTD; The files don't have dtd declaration and I can't change this because I am not the owner,
Is there a way of validating them using dom4j by providing the DTD separately?

Thanks

Comment: If push comes to shove, you can always run the input through a pipeline that inserts the string "<!DOCTYPE ... SYSTEM 'my.dtd'>" at the top of the input document, after any existing XML declaration.  (Better, of course, if there's a less hacky way, but there I can't help you.)

Comment: yes, that's the problem; I have to validate about 250 files at once so looking for a better option :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always convert the DTD to a schema (using for example [trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html)), and perform an in-memory validation against the schema for each document.

To do that, you would create one `javax.xml.validation.ValidationHandler` with the converted schema, and feed it to a DOM4J `SAXWriter`.

Another option is of course to

1. Parse each document without validation into a DOM4J `Document`
2. Add a DOM4j `DefaultDocumentType` to the parsed document
3. Write the document to a temporary string buffer
4. Parse again, but this time with a validating `SAXReader`